# Quick way to change suitebar color in MySites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, mysites

Is there a quick way to change the blue suitebar color on MySites site collection?

I have a custom CSS stylesheet and a custom MasterPage for my main WebApplication. But this ofc does not get deployed to my MySites WebApplication. I think that I will be able to locate the SharePoint standard CSS file that styles the suitebar and change it there, but I do not like to change in the standard files.

Is it possible to make a copy of the standard MySites MasterPage, add my CSS connection to that MasterPage and deploy it to the MySites WebApp, or is there a other way/practice?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked in to custom actions? Or feature stapling (http://sharepointologic.blogspot.se/2013/04/branding-sharepoint-2013-my-sites-with.html)?

Comment: This could be the solution to my problem. But would it not be easier just to create a new MySites Masterpage in my current solution and attach a CSS reference to it, and then change the masterpage in MySites WebApplication, or is it impossible to manually change MasterPage in MySites WebApplication?

Comment: That is not possible. The master page is by default set per site collection, but can be set per site. It can not be set on a web application level